# Python 3 SOCKSIPY Module prints error

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, socks

I downloaded the socks.py file and placed it in the python lib folder. When I run this script:

```
import socks
import socket
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "localhost", 9150)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.google.ca'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print (soup)
```

it sends an error like this:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Raphael/Desktop/whatsmyip.py", line 8, in <module>
    r = requests.get(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 68, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1088, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1126, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1084, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 922, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 857, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 155, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 134, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 78, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socks.py", line 369, in connect
    self.__negotiatesocks5(destpair[0],destpair[1])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/socks.py", line 176, in __negotiatesocks5
    self.sendall("\x05\x01\x00")
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`

Can someone help me? I do not know how to fix this.. No where explains what I need to do in this case. Thank you very much